# Android Room Bug in Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, compiler-warnings, android-room

I think the is a semantic issue in Room while working in Kotlin.
Simple `DAO` query in Room can be obtained by

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :id")
fun getUser(id: Int): User
```

Although, I defined return type as `User`, not `User?`, this query can still returns null, when there is no **User** with the given **id**.

So whenever you call this function, you definitely need to check for `null` return, as below

```
val user = userDao.getUser("someid")
if (user != null){
    return user
}
else {
    return DEFAULT_USER
}
```

But since we defined return type of `getUser` as `User`, @kotlin compiler suggest that `null` check is **redundant**.

Am I missing something? Can anyone give some feedback on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's already tracked issue in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112323132)
And as a respond they developers say

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> this is not about generated code
>   though, you are the person who creates that Query method so you should
>   declare it as nullable.

So, if we know that our code can return `null`, we should declare it as `Nullable` as

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :id")
fun getUser(id: Int): User?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no semantic issue. If Your function can return a null, it should be defined in the function return type. So, your function signature should be like this

```
fun getUser(id: Int): User?
```

This means the function can return null and now your null checks should work fine.

Comment: Yes, technically since my function can return null, I should have made return type `User?`. But what I am saying is, even if it is `User`, it can send `null`.

Comment: Your app will most probably get an exception  `null cannot be cast to non-null`  when your function will return. Kotlin doesn't know whether its a room function or a normal function.

Comment: my point was that, it does not give such exception. It will work as smooth as butter.. That's is indeed a bug